# Aliases for tailwind classes?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I want to change the name of the tailwind `hidden` class so that whenever I want to use `display:none`, I can do so by using the word `no-display` instead of using the word `hidden`. I am assuming this is a change I can make in the tailwind config file but I can't seem to figure out exactly how and what changes need to be made in that file. Thanks for the help

Comment: Depending on how you're using it, I'd just go find the `.hidden {...` class and change it to `.hidden, .no-display {...`

Comment: `hidden` is the tailwind utility class for `display:none`, I want to change that name but am unsure of where to go to change that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [add custom utilities](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#adding-custom-utilities) to your tailwind `CSS` file.

---

With the `@apply` directive:

`main.css`:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer utilities {
  .no-display {
    @apply hidden
  }
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="no-display">You can't see this text</div>
```

[Tailwind-play link](https://play.tailwindcss.com/7aDDObxR1k)

---

With `CSS` utility:

`main.css`:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer utilities {
  .no-display {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="no-display">You can't see this text</div>
```

[Tailwind-play link](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Z3pI9EGDxy?file=css)